# How to correctly inherit thread culture in a parallel block?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, globalization, currentculture

I'm using automatic globalization on an ASP MVC website. It works fine until it reached a parallel block:

```
public ActionResult Index() 
{
     // Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture is automatically set to "fr-FR"
     // according to the requested "Accept-Language" header

     Parallel.Foreach(ids, id => {
        // Not every thread in this block has the correct culture. 
        // Some of them still have the default culture "en-GB"
     }) ; 

     return View()
}
```

What is the best way to make the parallel block inherit the culture? apart from this solution:

```
public ActionResult Index() 
{
     var currentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture  ;

     Parallel.Foreach(ids, id => {
         // I don't know if it's threadsafe or not. 
         Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = currentCulture ; 

     }) ; 

     return View()
}
```

Comment: Probably, one of them has the culture of the request because of task inlining. The other ones should follow thread pool behavior whatever that is (I never found out).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your own `Parallel.ForEach` handling thread culture :

```
public static class ParallelInheritCulture
{
    public static ParallelLoopResult ForEach<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> body)
    {
        var parentThreadCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture; 
        var parentThreadUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture; 

        return Parallel.ForEach(source, e =>
        {
            var currentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture; 
            var currentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture; 

            try
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = parentThreadCulture;
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = parentThreadUICulture;

                body(e); 
            }
            finally
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = currentCulture;
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = currentUICulture;
            }
        }); 
    }
}
```

Then:

```
 ParallelInheritCulture.Foreach(ids, id => {
    // Whatever

 }) ;
```

Comment: What's the need to revert the culture inside parallel.?